# Как вытащить первый item xml?

Tags: python, xml

Есть xml файл такой конструкции

```
<channel>
    <item>
        <link></link>
    </item>
    <item>
        <link></link>
    </item>
</channel>
```

Как из него выбрать первый элемент item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из документации по работе с XML в Python:

Сначала прочитаем данные из файла и получим корневой элемент дерева XML. Не забудь название своего файла подставить.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

После этого легко получаем первый элемент:

```
first_element = root[0]
```

Если нужно пробежаться по всем элементам и вывести инфо:

```
for child in root:
  print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

Comment: Работать с xml легко. Нужно лишь в гугле написать "Python xml"